# Constraining button size

Tags: button, size, constraints

I need to constrain this button so the yellow border fits perfectly around the plus, just like the "Go".
[image]

Here is the button's CSS, for aid:

```
 #addinput{
        border-radius: 10px;
        font-family: 'Belgrano', serif;
        color: #FFE200;
        text-shadow: 0px -1px 1.9px #fff, 0px 3px 2px #000;
        background:transparent;
        font-size: 3em;
        height:50%;
        background-size: 40% auto;
        display:block;
        border:1px solid yellow;
    }
```

pic 2

[image]

Comment: Height not in relative percentage value, but in absolute value(e.g. px) will definitely help!

Comment: @yabol this happens (see pic 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set height value in px, and line-height maybe a little less, also in px. See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e8JH9/3/).

```
#addinput{
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-family: 'Belgrano', serif;
    color: #FFE200;
    text-shadow: 0px -1px 1.9px #fff, 0px 3px 2px #000;
    font-size: 3em;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `height:50%` is causing it to stretch, if you remove that the border will fit perfectly around it all the way.

Comment: no, it goes back as in the first image, with all that extra space above and below

Answer (score 0):

You can try wrapping the + in a paragraph inside the container:

```
​<div id="addinput"><p>+</p></div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Then the CSS would be:

```
#addinput p {
  margin-bottom: -10px; 
  margin-top: -10px;     
}
```